# how to implement multiple script tags specific to the user that will inject a widget into their website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, embed, cdn

I'm trying to create a service where users can embed a customer feedback widget in their website, similar to https://appzi.com. I'm thinking about using NodeJS for the BE but I'm confused as to how to generate unique script tags for each widget? And how to host those scripts? i searched all over google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

For hosting you could serve the files on an api endpoint and then res.send the files back with a fastify api. You could use a script tag and as a source use your api url and add a id to your script tag to identify. `<script src="https://yourapientpoint.something.com" id="widgetId" />` You can then in your widget subtract this id to determine the look of your widget.
Alternatively you could check https://www.jsdelivr.com/